# Ionic cordova-plugin-camera not opening gallery on Android

Tags: android, ionic3, cordova-plugin-camera

I'm trying to let user to select image from gallery on my ionic native app, code works on IOS but on android when select Choose Image nothing happend, can't see a error on logcat.

My method:

```
accessGallery(){
    this.camera.getPicture({
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType. SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      quality: 10
     }).then((imageData) => {
        this.sanitizeImage('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
      }, (err) => {
       console.log(err);
       this.showAlert("Cannot Access Gallery", err);
     });
   }
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Android.

```
 const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 10
    , destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    , mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE // Try this
    , sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
 };
```

The only difference is that I don't sanitize the text when I get the result.
I just do `this.myPicture = image64;`

Try with that and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Thanks.. i got it to work, the problem causing is plugin, when i removed the plugin it worked.